# Insufficient disk space; try again later when trying to send mail

Tags: php, sendmail, email, disk-space-utilization

I am trying to send an email with attachment using PHP and I get this error:

```
Insufficient disk space; try again later
Insufficient disk space; try again later
returntosender: cannot select queue for root
Insufficient disk space; try again later
returntosender: cannot select queue for postmaster
queueup: cannot create queue file qfp5M7HeoG001376, euid=51, fd=-1, fp=0x0: No space left on device
```

I checked and it seems that there is space:

```
Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
112G   89G   18G  84% /
 99M   22M   73M  23% /boot
4.9G   33M  4.6G   1% /tmp
4.9G  4.6G     0 100% /var
```

The file I'm trying to attach has less than 4MB.
Any idea where this comes from and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously there is not space in /var which is where it will try & create the spool